# How to Download the .exe file from the server and Install it

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Hi Everyone I have a server in which I update the .exe files I want to search the specific link for exe files and download it and install it using python.
I use this code but how to install the .exe file. and is this logic is correct. because it run without any error. but it did't show the output.

```
import urllib2


filepath = urllib2.urlopen('http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/')
file_name = ''
for i in filepath:
    file_name = i
completepath = filepath+file_name
datatowrite = completepath.read()

with open('/Users/scott/Downloads/cat2.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(datatowrite)
```

Answer (score 0):

To install the exe file, all you have to do is to run it.

```
import os
current_dir = r"C:\Downloads"
subprocess.Popen(os.path.join(current_dir,"file.exe"))
```

You'll also need to run the command prompt as administrator.

Comment: bro I tried it. it now downloading the file from my server.